# Skip some x tick labels when using `xtick=data`

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am plotting some csv data with

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{custom}{%
    red,mark=diamond*\\blue,mark=square*\\green!60!black,mark=otimes*\\%
    yellow,mark=*\\magenta,mark=star\\cyan,mark=*\\%
};

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{./data/valuation.csv}{\loadedtable};

\begin{axis}[
    width=15cm,
    height=8cm,
    grid=both,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    no marks,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{Date},
    tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east},
    cycle list name=custom,
    legend style={at={(0.025,0.95)},anchor=north west},
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{Ford, GM, Uber}{
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=#1] {\loadedtable};
    \addlegendentry{#1};
}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

yielding the plot

[image]

As seen in the figure, there is an empty space before (left) and after (right) the data, and all the x tick labels are very close to each other.

How can I remove the whitespace and skip some of the x tick labels? I have tried `xtick distance=5` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use xtick=data.  You can construct a list of tick values from \pgfplotstablegetelem and use xtick/.expanded={\list}

Comment: To get rid of the white space, use [enlarge x limits=false].

Comment: Did the tricks of John Kormylo solve your problems or do you need further assistance?